# Update with self join subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

Question:

> A supervisor (`employee_id` equals to `114`) has resigned from the
>   company, and today is the last day of work. With immediate effect, the
>   department he manages, and all those employees he supervises will be
>   taken over by his supervisor

So my syntax i came up with is:

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE
   SET supervisor_id = (SELECT supervisor_id
                          FROM EMPLOYEE
                         WHERE employee_id = '114'),
 WHERE supervisor_id = '114';
```

OUTPUT: 
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'EMPLOYEE' for update in FROM clause

but its wrong. I know the `supervisor_id = 100` however i do not just want to put `SET supervisor_id = 100` as it doesn't seem fair to put `100` *directly*. Can anyone help me correct?

Comment: I don't understand what your issue is.  Except for the trailing comma, you code looks reasonable.

Comment: Try adding *alias* `(SELECT e.supervisor_id
FROM EMPLOYEE e
WHERE e.employee_id ='114')`

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: sorry my bad im using ubuntu's mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE a 
  join 
     ( SELECT supervisor_id
            , employee_id  
         FROM EMPLOYEE 
        WHERE employee_id = '114'
     ) b 
    on a.supervisor_id = b.employee_id 
   set a.supervisor_id = b.supervisor_id
```

use this query

Comment: There's no need for a subquery here

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can't reference same table for `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE`. But you can use a sub-query here as a workaround.
Try something like below...

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE 
   SET EMPLOYEE.supervisor_id = (SELECT supervisor_id
                                  FROM (SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE) EmpFull
                                 WHERE employee_id = '114'),
 WHERE supervisor_id = '114';
```

Ref [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html)